# How should data for parametrized tests be prepared?

Tags: c++, googletest

I've started using gtest recently, and have run into a problem. I want to run a set of tests on files in folder, which should be enumerated for that to happen. I have managed to create test and instantiate t with data from the list of files, but have run into a problem of conceptual kind.

What i did was to create a global list to hold file names and fill it before `testing::InitGoogleTest` is called. that works.

However, the fact that i use global variables is bothering me. I have tried to move list initialisation into my own descendant of `testing::Environment`, but that caused the test instantiations to fail. To be more precise, list was filled but no tests were run using data from it.

So, my questions are:

1. What kind of data are sublasses of `testing::Environment` supposed to hold?
2. What would be proper way of initialising parametrized tests with dynamically generated lists?

Answer (score 0):

1. That's entirely up to you.
2. There is no 'proper' way. If you abhor global variables, you can create a global function or a static class method that loads test parameters from disc and returns them in a container (vector, list, etc.) and use that method in the test instantiation macro.

E.g.:

```
std::vector<std::string> LoadValuesFromDisc() {
  std::vector<std::string> result;
  // Fill in result with data here...
  return result;  // RVO will ensure there are no unnecessary copies.
}

INSTANTIATE_TEST_CASE_P(
    InstantiationName, TestFixture, testing::ValuesIn(LoadValuesFromDisc());
```

Comment: Seems counter-intuitive, to be honest. Maybe my expectations of how these parts of framework should interact just differ from reality.

Maybe i should just be thankful i can launch tests on dynamically generated lists at all.